# python removing weird characters

Tags: python, regex, function

I am trying to remove any sentences that contain weird characters like the one below which has many weird underscores.

```
sentence=='"____ __,_____________.._____________________"
```

I first create a function that spots the weird character and if true, we ignore that sentence:

```
    def underscore_filter(s):
        return "____ __," in s

    filter_fn_list = [underscore_filter]

    for fn in filter_fn_list:
        if fn(sentence):
            filter_match = True
            break
        if filter_match == True:
            continue
```

So really the problem only lies with the function part:

```
 def underscore_filter(s):
     return "____ __," in s
```

I just dont understand that despite returning the exact same underscore pattern in my function, the output for that function when i call it is always false. What is wrong and how can i re-write this code? i still need it to be in this similar format.

I added "continue" at the end because my code is actually reading through rows of a CSV file. If the row contains weird characters, i will skip that row.

Comment: Your indentation is a bit kludgy.  It could be an artifact of figuring out the markdown renderer on StackOverflow, or you could be mixing spaces and tabs (don't do that ... run with `python -t yourscript.py` to get a warning about that problem).  In any event, the code you posted seems suspect.  `filter_fn_list = [underscore_filter(s)]` will be either `[True]` or `[False]` (depending on `s`) which doesn't match at all with it's usage later... In fact, with this code, I'd expect an exception of some sort...

Comment: Btw, according to your code `if filter_match == True: continue` is totally unnecessary.

Comment: Why are underscores weird?  To be fair, they probably think you are.

Comment: For future questions, please include *current* and *complete* code examples in your questions. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It prevents people from wasting time pointing out things in your code that are irrelevant to the problem at hand, or are errors that you've already fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this by `lambda`.

```
def underscore_filter(s):
    return "____ __," in s

filter_match = False
sentence = "____ __,_____________.._____________________"

filter_fn_list = [ lambda s:underscore_filter(s) ]

for fn in filter_fn_list:
    if fn(sentence):
        filter_match = True
        break

print filter_match
```

By the way, I don't understand why you added the `continue` part in the cycle, in my opinion it's totally unnecessary, so I just dropped it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this line:

```
filter_fn_list=[underscore_filter(s)]
```

What it does that it returns True or False into filter_fn_list. However, I think you want to make a list of functions which you can call later in a loop. Thus you should do:

```
filter_fn_list=[underscore_filter]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making this more complicated than it needs to be. Try this simpler alternative using list comprehensions:

```
# list of sentences we want to filter
sentences = ["abcd", "a____ __,", "sdf", "ghke_______kh"]

# list of patterns we want to filter out
bad_patterns = ["____ __,", "_______"]

# perform the filtering
filtered_sentences = [s for s in sentences 
    if not any(pattern in s for pattern in bad_patterns)]
```

Printing the resulting `filtered_sentences` list produces this output:

> ['abcd', 'sdf']